# Group the objects by Board name

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, arraylist, lodash

I am having a long JSON which is array of objects. Each Element has property *name* and *boards*. I need to club them on the basis of the boards name.

```
[
  {
    "name": "school education",
    "boards": [
      {
        "name": "CBSE",
        "grades": [
          {
            "name": "class 1",
            "subject": [
              "french"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "school education",
    "boards": [
      {
        "name": "CBSE",
        "grades": [
          {
            "name": "class 1",
            "subject": [
              "physical education"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "school education",
    "boards": [
      {
        "name": "CBSE",
        "grades": [
          {
            "name": "class 1",
            "subject": [
              "chinese"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "school education",
    "boards": [
      {
        "name": "CBSE",
        "grades": [
          {
            "name": "class 1",
            "subject": [
              "sanskrit"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "school education",
    "boards": [
      {
        "name": "CBSE",
        "grades": [
          {
            "name": "class 1",
            "subject": [
              "spanish"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "school education",
    "boards": [
      {
        "name": "CBSE",
        "grades": [
          {
            "name": "class 1",
            "subject": [
              "russian"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "school education",
    "boards": [
      {
        "name": "JKBOSE",
        "grades": [
          {
            "name": "class 1",
            "subject": [
              "french"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "school education",
    "boards": [
      {
        "name": "JKBOSE",
        "grades": [
          {
            "name": "class 1",
            "subject": [
              "physical education"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "school education",
    "boards": [
      {
        "name": "JKBOSE",
        "grades": [
          {
            "name": "class 1",
            "subject": [
              "chinese"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "school education",
    "boards": [
      {
        "name": "JKBOSE",
        "grades": [
          {
            "name": "class 1",
            "subject": [
              "sanskrit"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "school education",
    "boards": [
      {
        "name": "JKBOSE",
        "grades": [
          {
            "name": "class 1",
            "subject": [
              "spanish"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "school education",
    "boards": [
      {
        "name": "JKBOSE",
        "grades": [
          {
            "name": "class 1",
            "subject": [
              "russian"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am having the above JSON and i need to convert it into this format. So my JSON will now have one key of *name* which consists of the

> school Education
> and other key *boards* which will have all the items grouped on the basis of name.

```
name: "school education",
    boards: [
      {
        name: "CBSE",
        grades: [
          {
            name: "Class 1",
            subjects: ["Maths", "Hindi", "EVS", "English"]
          },
          {
            name: "Class 2",
            subjects: ["Maths", "Hindi", "EVS", "English"]
          },
          {
            name: "Class 3",
            subjects: ["Maths", "Hindi", "EVS", "English"]
          },
          {
            name: "Class 4",
            subjects: ["Maths", "Hindi", "EVS", "English"]
          },
          {
            name: "Class 5",
            subjects: ["Maths", "Hindi", "EVS", "English"]
          },
          {
            name: "Class 6",
            subjects: [
              "Maths",
              "Hindi",
              "English",
              "History",
              "Geography",
              "Civics",
              "Sanskrit",
              "Science"
            ]
          },
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

What you are effectively doing is grouping and mapping at each level.

You need to group by item name; then inside each item, group by board; and in each board, group by grades. This gets more complex for each nested item.

```js
const main = () => {
  const result = _.chain(data())
    .groupBy('name')
    .map((value1, key1) => ({
      name: key1,
      boards: _.chain(value1)
        .groupBy('boards[0].name')
        .map((value2, key2) => ({
          name: key2,
          grades: _.chain(value2)
            .groupBy('boards[0].grades[0].name')
            .map((value3, key3) => ({
              name: value3[0].boards[0].grades[0].name,
              subjects: _.flattenDeep(value3.map(item => {
                return item.boards.map(board => {
                  return board.grades.map(grade => {
                    return grade.subject;
                  })
                })
              }))
            }))
        }))
    }))
    .value();
    
  console.log(result);
};

const data = () => [{
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "CBSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["french"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "CBSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["physical education"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "CBSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["chinese"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "CBSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["sanskrit"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "CBSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["spanish"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "CBSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["russian"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "JKBOSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["french"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "JKBOSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["physical education"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "JKBOSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["chinese"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "JKBOSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["sanskrit"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "JKBOSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["spanish"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "JKBOSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["russian"]
    }]
  }]
}];

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

Alternatively, this is how you could do it without a library.

```js
const main = () => {
  const nameGroups = data().reduce((result, item) => {
    return {
      ...result,
      [item.name]: [ ...(result[item.name] || []), item.boards ]
    }
  }, {});
  const result = Object.keys(nameGroups).map(key => {
    const boardGroups = nameGroups[key].flat().reduce((result, board) => {
      return {
        ...result,
        [board.name]: [ ...(result[board.name] || []), board.grades ]
      }
    }, {});
    return {
      name: key,
      boards: Object.keys(boardGroups).map(board => {
        const gradeGroups = boardGroups[board].flat().reduce((res, grade) => {
          return {
            ...res,
            [grade.name]: [ ...(res[grade.name] || []), grade.subject ].flat()
          }
        }, {});
        return {
          name: board,
          grades: Object.keys(gradeGroups).map(key => {
            return {
              name: key,
              subjects: gradeGroups[key]
            }
          })
        }
      })
    }
  });
  
  console.log(result);
};

const data = () => [{
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "CBSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["french"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "CBSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["physical education"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "CBSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["chinese"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "CBSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["sanskrit"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "CBSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["spanish"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "CBSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["russian"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "JKBOSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["french"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "JKBOSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["physical education"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "JKBOSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["chinese"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "JKBOSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["sanskrit"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "JKBOSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["spanish"]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "school education",
  "boards": [{
    "name": "JKBOSE",
    "grades": [{
      "name": "class 1",
      "subject": ["russian"]
    }]
  }]
}];

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a concise approach which loop to a level of a key of the children array and use a recursion for every level.

```js
function groupBy(source, [key, ...keys], target = []) {
    const
        group = ({ name, [key]: values }) => {
            let item = target.find(q => q.name === name);
            if (!item) target.push(item = { name, [key]: [] });
            groupBy(values, keys, item[key]);
        };

    if (key) source.forEach(group);
    else target.push(...source);

    return target;
}

const
    data = [{ name: "school education", boards: [{ name: "CBSE", grades: [{ name: "class 1", subject: ["french"] }] }] }, { name: "school education", boards: [{ name: "CBSE", grades: [{ name: "class 1", subject: ["physical education"] }] }] }, { name: "school education", boards: [{ name: "CBSE", grades: [{ name: "class 1", subject: ["chinese"] }] }] }, { name: "school education", boards: [{ name: "CBSE", grades: [{ name: "class 1", subject: ["sanskrit"] }] }] }, { name: "school education", boards: [{ name: "CBSE", grades: [{ name: "class 1", subject: ["spanish"] }] }] }, { name: "school education", boards: [{ name: "CBSE", grades: [{ name: "class 1", subject: ["russian"] }] }] }, { name: "school education", boards: [{ name: "JKBOSE", grades: [{ name: "class 1", subject: ["french"] }] }] }, { name: "school education", boards: [{ name: "JKBOSE", grades: [{ name: "class 1", subject: ["physical education"] }] }] }, { name: "school education", boards: [{ name: "JKBOSE", grades: [{ name: "class 1", subject: ["chinese"] }] }] }, { name: "school education", boards: [{ name: "JKBOSE", grades: [{ name: "class 1", subject: ["sanskrit"] }] }] }, { name: "school education", boards: [{ name: "JKBOSE", grades: [{ name: "class 1", subject: ["spanish"] }] }] }, { name: "school education", boards: [{ name: "JKBOSE", grades: [{ name: "class 1", subject: ["russian"] }] }] }],
    result = groupBy(data, ['boards', 'grades', 'subject']);
   
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```